# Azure SQL DB replication issue

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Sync failed with the exception

> Sync was aborted because more than 1000 changes failed to apply.
>   Examine your table schemas to look for conflicting constraints or
>   incompatible data types that may prevent sync from succeeding.
>   Download - errors for first 5 rows that failed to apply: Error #1:
>   SqlException Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:257, Message:
>   SQL error with code 257 Error #2: SqlException Error Code: -2146232060
>   - SqlError Number:257, Message: SQL error with code 257 Error #3: SqlException Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:257, Message:
>   SQL error with code 257 Error #4: SqlException Error Code: -2146232060
>   - SqlError Number:257, Message: SQL error with code 257 Error #5: SqlException Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:257, Message:
>   SQL error with code 257 For more information, provide tracing ID
>   ‘7c1ca4ff-0b92-4953-adaf-a27c98b3c55f’ to customer support.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, are the schemas identical in the databases?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made any schema changes recently? Any change on the database schema of the hub database or any member database should be manually propagated to all other databases because SQL Data Sync does not support dynamic schema changes. Changes to schema include: changing the name of indexes, columns and tables; adding objects, indexes or adding columns to tables. Take in consideration that changes to server names are not supported too.

Make sure primary keys are not getting updated because is not supported.